# Android + Json inserting part of spinner value into mysql via php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, spinner

How to get just -part- of a spinner's value?

What i mean is my spinner shows:

"34 | Stress Shot #01" with json data from mysql via php.

In the activity i want to send some data to update a table and from the spinner i want only the "34" not the rest of the string. 
Is it possible to acomplish? i've searched but haven't really found anything

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data will be always the number to show followed by "|".

```
String yourString = "34 | Stress Shot #01";
String[] parts = string.split("\\|"); // Splitting your string with character "|". SO you will get "34 " and " Stress Shot #01"
String iNeeded = parts[0];// You need the first part only
```